# Benchmark function with input that doesn't implement the Copy trait

Tags: rust, ownership, rust-criterion

I am running benchmarks with Criterion but am facing issues with functions that have an input that does not implement the Copy trait.

For example, I have set up the following benchmark for a function with the signature `pub fn hash(vector: Vec<&str>) -> u64`.

```
pub fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let s: String = String::from("Hello World!");
    let tokens: Vec<&str> = hashing::tokenize(&s);
    c.bench_function(
        "hash",
        |b| b.iter(|| {
            hashing::hash(tokens)
        }),
    );
}
```

However, unlike with types that have the Copy trait, the compiler throws out the following ownership error.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `tokens`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> benches/benchmark.rs:17:34
   |
13 |     let tokens: Vec<&str> = hashing::tokenize(&s);
   |         ------ captured outer variable
...
17 |             hashing::hash(tokens)
   |                                  ^^^^^^ move occurs because `tokens` has type `Vec<&str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `tokens`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> benches/benchmark.rs:16:20
   |
13 |     let tokens: Vec<&str> = hashing::tokenize(&s);
   |         ------ captured outer variable
...
16 |         |b| b.iter(|| {
   |                    ^^ move out of `tokens` occurs here
17 |             hashing::hash(tokens)
   |                                  ------
   |                                  |
   |                                  move occurs because `tokens` has type `Vec<&str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                                  move occurs due to use in closure
```

How can non-copyable inputs be passed to the benchmarked function without running into ownership issues?

Comment: The real problem seems to be in the benchmarked hashing function. Can't you just fix it to accept `&[&str]` (and call it with `hashing::hash(&tokens)`) ? Why would hashing need a vec ?

Comment: why not clone it ?

Comment: @Stargateur Cloning the parameter solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Stargateur Could the overhead of cloning the vector affect the benchmark?

Comment: @bergwald Yes, it will. Criterion has tools to compute it separately, though. But your current prototype means every use of the hashing function will pay this price too. Hence my suggestion above.

Comment: @bergwald yes, of course, since you use criterion you could consider using https://docs.rs/criterion/0.3.5/criterion/struct.Bencher.html#method.iter_batched that should reduce the impact of cloning overhead

Comment: @Stargateur @DenysSéguret Results: Cloning the function has a ~50% overhead compared to accepting `&[&str]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Stargateur, cloning the parameter solved the ownership issue.

```
pub fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let s: String = String::from("Hello World!");
    let tokens: Vec<&str> = hashing::tokenize(&s);
    c.bench_function(
        "hash",
        |b| b.iter(|| {
            hashing::hash(tokens.clone())
        }),
    );
}
```

However, as proposed by @DenysSéguret and @Masklinn, changing the `hash` function to accept `&[&str]` avoids the ~50% overhead of cloning the vector.

Comment: Alternatively if you can update `hash` to take a slice, you could `move` the tokens in the closure and simply lend them to the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Cloning the input can result in severe errors in the benchmark result.

Therefore you should use [`iter_batched()`](https://docs.rs/criterion/0.3.5/criterion/struct.Bencher.html#method.iter_batched) instead of [`iter()`](https://docs.rs/criterion/0.3.5/criterion/struct.Bencher.html#method.iter)

```rust
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, BatchSize, BenchmarkId, Criterion};
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

criterion_main!(benches);
criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let input_data: String = String::from("Hello World!");

    c.bench_function("bench_function", |bencher| {
        bencher.iter_batched(
            || init_data(&input_data),
            |input| {
                let x = benchmark_me(input);
                black_box(x);
            },
            BatchSize::SmallInput,
        );
    });

    c.bench_function("bench_function+clone", |bencher| {
        bencher.iter(|| {
            let x = benchmark_me(init_data(&input_data));
            black_box(x);
        });
    });
}

fn init_data(s: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    // it's intentionally slower than a plain copy, to make the difference more visible!
    s.split_ascii_whitespace().collect()
}

fn benchmark_me(s: Vec<&str>) -> u64 {
    let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
    s.hash(&mut hasher);
    hasher.finish()
}
```

Results:

````
bench_function                  time:   [99.520 ns 100.90 ns 102.23 ns]                           
bench_function+clone            time:   [210.41 ns 212.08 ns 213.77 ns]                                                                                                     ```
````